# Capturing group eat some characters

Tags: java, regex

My input is like this :

```
line 1
**ER1.RIAA.SOMPSFIO(LIAOEE)         UTGD788  FDSJOFUZZÃ„                                                                                                                                                                              line2      
JNDJZSDS ER1.RIAA.SIMEDFUA(AUDD)                YIRIHFIH1465EZZÃ„     

line 3
UJZRJOERERÃLDE,UIE='UJ1.DHZKZ5.OZDEZN98.AAERRE',I=DZEDE                   POPZEOE**
```

I would like to get only characters with periods , ie :

```
ER1.RIAA.SOMPSFIO
ER1.RIAA.SIMEDFUA
UJ1.DHZKZ5.OZDEZN98.AAERRE
```

My solution is that :

```
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        nrligne++;

int counter = 0;

for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++ ) {
    if( line.charAt(i) == '.' ) {
        counter++;
    }
}

if (counter == 2) {

    if (line.matches("^.*[A-Z0-9]+\\..[A-Z1-9]+.*$")){

        line= removeTroublesomeCharacters(line);
        System.out.println("ligne vaut "+line);

        Pattern dsnPattern = Pattern.compile("^.*([A-Z0-9]+)\\..([A-Z1-9]+)\\..([A-Z1-9]+).*$");
        Matcher m = dsnPattern.matcher(line);

        if (m.matches()) {
            String part1   = m.group(1);
            String part2   = m.group(2);
            String part3   = m.group(3);

            System.out.println("part1 vaut "+part1);
            System.out.println("part2 vaut "+part2);
            System.out.println("part2 vaut "+part3);
        }               
    }
```

For the moment the result is

```
ligne vaut ï»¿ER1.RIAA.SOMPSFIO(LIAOEE)                                                                                             UTGD788
part1 vaut 1
part2 vaut IAA
part2 vaut OMPSFIO
ligne vaut PZFDSJOFUZZÃâ                                                                                                                                                                                    ER1.RIAA.SIMEDFUA(AUDD)                                                                                             UOOO88
part1 vaut 1
part2 vaut IAA
part2 vaut IMEDFUA
ligne vaut UJZRJOERERÃLDE,UIE='UJ1.DHZKZ5.OZDEZN98',I=DZEDE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      POPZEOE
part1 vaut 1
part2 vaut HZKZ5
part2 vaut ZDEZN98
```

File in input : http://uploadhero.co/dl/PWBLhi7d
I don't understand why the regex eat the begin of each characters ? Can someone help me to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are consuming an extra character after the `dot`, and not including it in character class.

```
\\..   // this will match a dot, and then following single character.
```

Also, make the `.*` at the beginning of your regex to `.*?`. Since quantifiers are by default greedy, they will consume all the characters, and just leave a single word just before the `.` to be matched by `([a-z0-9]+)`.

Change your regex to:

```
"^.*?([A-Z0-9]+)\\.([A-Z1-9]+)\\.([A-Z1-9]+).*$"
```

---

Also, since you are using `Pattern` and `Matcher` anyways, I will consider using the `Matcher#find()` method, and build pattern just for the part that I need:

```
Pattern dsnPattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z0-9]+)\\.([A-Z1-9]+)\\.([A-Z1-9]+)");
Matcher m = dsnPattern.matcher(line);

if (m.find()) {
```

Comment: You still have two periods in the regex itself. Don't you meant to only have one?

Answer (score 1):

Since the capturing parts of your expression are preceded and followed by "eat anything" `.*` expression, part of what you wish to capture ends up being consumed by these "fillers".

You can explicitly require that the characters before and after `[A-Z0-9]+` groups be non-alphanumeric, like this:

```
   "^.*(?<![A-Z0-9])([A-Z0-9]+)\\.([A-Z1-9]+)\\.([A-Z1-9]+)(?![A-Z1-9]).*$"
```

- The `(?<![A-Z0-9])` expression means "not preceded by `[A-Z0-9]`"
- The `(?![A-Z1-9])` expression means "not followed by `[A-Z1-9]`"

**EDIT :**

The lookahead is not necessary, because `+` is greedy:

```
"^.*(?<![A-Z0-9])([A-Z0-9]+)\\.([A-Z1-9]+)\\.([A-Z1-9]+).*$"
```

(credit for this goes to [Rohit Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679863/rohit-jain))

Comment: `(?![A-Z1-9])` at the end is not needed, since `+` quantifier due to its greediness will consume all the words automatically.

Comment: Also, you can make the `.*` at the beginning to `.*?` to stop before the first character matching `[A-Z0-9]`.

Comment: @RohitJain Reluctant `.*?` may cause slowdown due to backtracking, especially with longer inputs with "false positives".

Comment: You got it. It works !  I understand what you say but i don't understand the expression : (?<![A-Z0-9]). Can you help me to understand ?

Comment: @John That's a negative look-behind. `(?<![A-Z0-9])([A-Z0-9]+)` means, match `([A-Z0-9]+)` not preceded by `[A-Z0-9]`. So, it will not start matching `[A-Z0-9]` from the middle of some word.

Comment: @John When you put `(?<! something )` before an expression, it means that the expression is going to match only when it is *not* preceded by "something", where "something" is another regular expression. This prevents the `.*` from "eating into" the string that you want to capture.